# Laravel 5.4: Using eloquent and fillable field to update multiple model with multiple table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two models `Driver` and `DriverCar`

I need to display the field values by model let me show you my code of my form header
Note that `Driver` are related to `DriverCar` by `driver_id`

```
{!! Form::model($driver, [
            'route'=>['drivers.update', $driver],
            'method'=>'PATCH',
            'class'=>'form-horizontal'
            ]) !!}
```

now in my form fields I have

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('name', trans('interface.DriverName'), ['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>trans('interface.DriverName')]) !!}
     </div>
</div>
```

which updated successfully when I update. but the `DriverCar` fields didn't get the `fillable` values if it's set to `null` I had to get it by relations like `$driver->driverCar->car_model`

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('car_model', trans('interface.carModel'), ['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-sm-10">
     {!! Form::text('car_model', $driver->driverCar->car_model, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>trans('interface.carModel')]) !!}
     </div>
</div>
```

is there is any way to get it `fillable` without giving it relations like that `$driver->driverCar->car_model`?

**second** 
here is my controller I try to updated the two tables at once

```
public function update( Request $request, Driver $driver, DriverCar $driverCar ) {
        //dd( $driverCar );
        $input = $request->all();
        $driver->fill( $input )->save();

        $driverCar->fill( $input )->save();

        return redirect()->route( 'drivers.edit', $driver );
    }
```

in controller too I can't update the two tables it just update the `Driver` but not touching the  `DriverCar`

any Guide please.

Comment: One to one relationship among driver and driver car ?

Comment: Yes it one to one relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing `driverCar` ID to the `update` controller method, so change code to something like this:

```
public function update( Request $request, Driver $driver)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $driver->fill($input)->save();
    $driver->driverCar()->first()->fill($input)->save();
    return redirect()->route('drivers.edit', $driver);
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks this solved the controller issue it worked any way to make the `fillable` happen in the form fields please? without using the value like this `$driver->driverCar->car_model` thanks